# Keep "auto hidden" taskbar in windows 10 hidden and revoke with windows key

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

I set the Taskbar in Windows 10 to "auto hide". Now when I need it i can toggle the Taskbar using the <kbd>Win</kbd> key.

But when the mouse cursor reaches the bottom or there are some "events" the Taskbar keeps popping up which I would like to prevent. Is this possible?

Comment: Old post here but may work in W10>>>>https://www.sevenforums.com/customization/170111-disable-auto-hide-taskbar-mouseover-popup.html

Comment: Also here>>>>>>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378861/windows-7-taskbar-disable-show-if-mouse-over